# NoClassDefFoundError on a class provided by jersey-core (UriComponent$Type)

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, weblogic-10.x

I am using WebLogic 10.2c. My webapp containing a jax-rs resource works fine in the grizzley but when it is deployed into WebLogic according to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13734/rest.htm, it throws a `NoClassDefFoundError` as shown below. The weird thing is that this class can indeed be loaded by my webapp with class.forName() done in my servlet. So, somehow that class has become unavailable for jersey itself. Any idea on how to troubleshoot? I've tried using jersey as a shared library (and thus not including into my .war file) and including jersey into my .war file. Either makes any difference.

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/uri/UriComponent$Type
     at com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl.appendPath(UriBuilderImpl.java:497)
     at com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl.appendPath(UriBuilderImpl.java:485)
     at com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl.replacePath(UriBuilderImpl.java:244)
     at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:687)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:235)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
     at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
     at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
     at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
     at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
     at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

Comment: Is the weblogic using a different jdk version? and if so is the class part of that jdk's endorsed lib or rt folder?

Comment: How is your war packaged? When you install it as a shared library, did you make sure to target it to your server hosting the web app?

Comment: hey, how you got to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Cleaning the project.
Top menu --   **Project --> clean.**
then Restart the server.
This worked for me.